# Dynamically render Angular 2 Material components

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im trying to have an attribute that when applied to a button, appends a loader to the inner content of the button.

The following appends a loader to the button content:

```
var test = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0], 'mat-spinner');
this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0], test);
```

The mat-spinner element is rendered in the HTML but the angular rendering isnt applied to it. Im guessing this is because of some angular intricacies.

Does anyone know of a way for me to render this element correctly at run time?

Thanks.

Comment: Please also add template code and mat-spinner css.

Comment: mat-spinner is an angular material component. I haven't coded any of the css myself.

Comment: What is this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0] element type?

Comment: it is a `span` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im trying to have an attribute that when applied to a button, appends
>   a loader to the inner content of the button

If I understand your question correctly, you could consider creating a custom button element that simply hides/shows the `mat-spinner` based on the attribute that you pass into this custom button component via [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) instead of appending the newly created spinner to the DOM.

As an example, if you have an attribute `myAttribute` who's value changes dynamically based on user interaction, you can "sync" this value into your custom button component in order to hide/show the spinner as needed, here is quick demo that demonstrates this approach:

**custom-button.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-button',
  template: `
    <button mat-button>
      <span>{{ options.text }}</span>
      <mat-spinner class="spinner" 
        [diameter]="options.spinnerSize" 
        *ngIf="options.myAttribute">
      </mat-spinner>
    </button>
  `
})
export class CustomButton {
  @Input() options: any;
}
```

When using this custom button in a component, the `mat-spinner` will already be part of the DOM:

**app.component.html**

```
<custom-button [options]="buttonOptions" (click)="someFunc()"></custom-button>
```

and can then be toggled dynamically based on your attribute value:

**app.components.ts**

```
export class AppComonent {

  buttonOptions: any = {
    myAttribute: false,
    text: 'Apply Attribute',
    spinnerSize: 18
  }

  someFunc() {
    // do something with the custom attribute
    this.buttonOptions.myAttribute = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.buttonOptions.myAttribute = false;
    }, 2500)
  }
}
```

`myAttribute` does not necessarily have to be a Boolean, it could be anything, you would just need to adjust the `ngIf` condition in the `custom-button` component.

There isn't very much context to your question unfortunately, but here is a [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custombuton) you can view which might help.

Comment: perfect. I dont know why I didn't think of this. I was overcomplicating things. Thanks!